# Most efficient way to create and query a grouped summary in R, and its Python equivalent

Tags: python, r, aggregate

Suppose you have an array of numerical values, and a corresponding array of integers that represent the group each numerical value belongs to.

You want to get the mean of the values by group, and identify which group has the highest mean.
[NOTE: instead of 'mean' we might want the 'median', or some other function, for the grouped summary].

Here is what I could come up with in `R`:

```
g <- c(7,1,0,2,1,1,7,4,4,1)
v <- c(0.35,0.2,0.45,0.5,0.43,0.57,0.62,0.11,0.23,0.72)

# Goal:
# - get the mean of the values in v grouped by the values in g
# - report the g value for which the grouped mean is maximal

# Using 'by'
b <- by(v, list(g), FUN = mean)
gbest <- dimnames(b)[[1]][which.max(b)]
print(gbest)

# Using 'aggregate'
a <- aggregate(v ~ g, FUN = mean)
gbest <- a[which.max(a$v),"g"]
print(gbest)

# Speed test
set.seed(1234)

by_time <- system.time({
  replicate(1000, {
    v <- runif(10, 0, 1)
    b <- by(v, list(g), FUN = mean)
    gbest <- dimnames(b)[[1]][which.max(b)]
    })
})
print(by_time)

aggregate_time <- system.time({
  replicate(1000, {
    v <- runif(10, 0, 1)
    a <- aggregate(v ~ g, FUN = mean)
    gbest <- a[which.max(a$v),"g"]
  })
})
print(aggregate_time)
```

On my PC, the `aggregate` method is about 2.5 times slower than the `by` one.

> **Do you think this is an efficient way of doing this? Or can you suggest better alternatives?**

Then, very importantly, I need to find a way to do this in `python`.
The only way I found so far was via `pandas`, using `groupby`.

Thing is, this needs to be as efficient as possible, because it is used in a loop.
At each iteration the loop calculates a new `v` (hence the use of `runif` in my code above).
In this example I left `g` constant; in real applications it sometimes is, whereas in other cases it is updated at each iteration by appending one integer to it, and `v` of course also increases in length by 1.

> **Any suggestions/pointers for a python implementation of this computation?**

---

**EDIT** using `tapply` as suggested by user Parfait (after adding `names` to obtain the actual desired result).

```
tapply_time <- system.time({
  replicate(1000, {
    v <- runif(10, 0, 1)
    grp_means <- tapply(v, g, mean)
    gbest <- which(grp_means == max(grp_means))
  })
})

print(tapply_time)
```

On my PC, this is about 2.5-2.8 times faster than `by`, so definitely preferable.

---

**EDIT** tests of `python` methods, as suggested by users Nikita Almakov and StupidWolf

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

from convtools import conversion as c

# this writes the necessary code and compiles the function (so do it outside
# the loop)
converter = (
    # here we group by first item of each tuple
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate({
        # here we can store & calculate whatever we want,
        # using fields in group by and any combination of reducers,
        # including custom reduce funcs
        "g": c.item(0),
        # there's a handful of ReduceFuncs -> https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#reduce-funcs-list
        "v_avg": c.ReduceFuncs.Average(c.item(1))
    })
    .pipe(c.aggregate(c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item("v_avg"))))
    .gen_converter(debug=True)  # if black is installed, this will print formatted code
)

g = [7, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 1]
v = [0.32, 0.2, 0.45, 0.5, 0.43, 0.57, 0.62, 0.11, 0.23, 0.72]

converter(zip(g, v))['g']    
# 2

v = np.random.uniform(0,1,10); converter(zip(g, v))['g']
# 0

%timeit v = np.random.uniform(0,1,10); converter(zip(g, v))['g']
# 22.6 µs ± 1.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

pd.Series(v).groupby(g).agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False).index[0]
# 2

%timeit v = np.random.uniform(0,1,10); pd.Series(v).groupby(g).agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False).index[0]
# 817 µs ± 3.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The fastest method in `R` (`tapply`) took 0.2 s for 1000 replicates, <del>so about 0.2 µs per loop</del>, if I am not mistaken.
EDIT: yes, I was mistaken! It is 0.2 *ms*, i.e. 200 µs per loop. Thanks Nikita for pointing it out!

Conclusion:

- implementing this calculation in `python` is possible without creating a `pandas` data frame at each iteration
- it seems that the best method so far is the one from `convtools`
- <del>it is still about 100 times slower than R</del> as per edit above, `convtools` is about 10 times faster than `R` `tapply`; `pandas` is about 4 times slower than `R` `tapply` (BTW I checked: the generation of the random uniform `v` by `numpy` has almost no (relative) impact on the total time, about 3.5 µs per loop)

Comment: in Python you can use the timeit module to check which is the faster method.

Comment: Thanks @FLAK-ZOSO , I can try that. My point here is to understand *how* I can do it in python. Creating a new pandas DataFrame at each iteration sounds costly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you're right. I don't know the answer, so I only suggessted a way to test the different ways to do this.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Back up and give us fuller context of loop needs. There may be efficient vectorized approaches.

Comment: Interesting you used `by` which is a wrapper to `tapply` that returns a vector and not a list: `grp_means <- tapply(v, g, mean); which(grp_means == max(grp_means))`.

Comment: @Parfait : sorry, I am not sure how you your comments are helping. I disagree about the XY stuff: I am really talking about the actual problem I am trying to solve. There is an algorithm that generates two lists, and I need to do the maths I am describing on those lists. I cannot possibly go into the very intricate details of where those lists come from. As for your second comment 'Interesting...', again, sorry, if you read my OP, I wrote 'can you suggest better alternatives?'. If you think you can, you can write an answer, I will thank you and upvote you. Why do it as a snide remark instead?

Comment: Hi I think @Parfait simply means, given your example, the fastest way is using tapply. I noticed there's many questions wrapped into this. What has the solution in R has to do with python?

Comment: Are you working with a numpy array, or a list in python? I think these are very ambiguous and wouldn't it make sense to just ask for a way to aggregate a list / array in python?

Comment: well, for what it's worth, `g = [7,1,0,2,1,1,7,4,4,1] 
 v= [0.35,0.2,0.45,0.5,0.43,0.57,0.62,0.11,0.23,0.72] pd.Series(v).groupby(g).agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: @StupidWolf : brilliant, thanks! I will include this in my tests right now. You people on SO are very knowledgeable, and that's why we simpler-minded non-computer-science-PhD's ask for your help :) I will publish the results shortly.

Comment: there's a typo to correct: 0.2s for 1000 iterations is 200 microseconds per iteration or 0.2 millisecond, not 0.2 microsecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [convtools](https://github.com/iTechArt/convtools) python library, which allows you to define conversions and when you are done, it writes & compiles ad-hoc python code under the hood, so you have the function which does the thing you wanted.

```py
# pip install convtools
from convtools import conversion as c

# this writes the necessary code and compiles the function (so do it outside
# the loop)
converter = (
    # here we group by first item of each tuple
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate({
        # here we can store & calculate whatever we want,
        # using fields in group by and any combination of reducers,
        # including custom reduce funcs
        "g": c.item(0),
        # there's a handful of ReduceFuncs -> https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#reduce-funcs-list
        "v_avg": c.ReduceFuncs.Average(c.item(1))
    })
    .pipe(c.aggregate(c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item("v_avg"))))
    .gen_converter(debug=True)  # if black is installed, this will print formatted code
)

g = [7, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 1]
v = [0.35, 0.2, 0.45, 0.5, 0.43, 0.57, 0.62, 0.11, 0.23, 0.72]

# passing iterable of tuples (g_item, v_item)
result = converter(zip(g, v))
print(result)
```

Should you have any questions, let me know - I'm happy to help!